# Trying to transfer data from one activity to another in android but it show null value on another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to transfer data from one activity to another activity in android but it show null value on another activity.

My Intent Code at first activity

```
 Intent  intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, WinnerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("correctAnswer", score);
            intent.putExtra("incorrectAnswer", incorrectAnswer);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Then in second activity i retrive argument like this:

```
  correctAnswers = getIntent().getExtras().getString("correctAnswer");
        incorrectAnswers = getIntent().getExtras().getString("incorrectAnswer");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct answer is " + "\n" + correctAnswers +
                "\n" + "Incorrect answers is " + incorrectAnswers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But toast is print both variables value null i don't know why.

Comment: how do we know `score` isn't null ?

Answer (score 0):

The values are null in the resultant activity because you are not setting the values in intent.getExtras () .

Use this method instead to get the values in WinnerActivity:

```
correctAnswers = getIntent().getStringExtra("correctAnswer");
incorrectAnswers = getIntent().getStringExtra("incorrectAnswer");
```

In QuizActivity:
If the values you are passing on to the next activity is still null check the values using log before passing to the next activity .

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Log.d("score",""+score);
Log.d("incorresct",""+incorrectAnswer);

intent.putString("correctAnswer", score); 
intent.putString("incorrectAnswer", incorrectAnswer); 
startActivity(intent);
```